# How to view Object at Memory Address?

Tags: java, jvm, jvm-crash

I have a thread dump and Memory dump of my process where a thread is hung

```
at sun.misc.Unsafe.park(Native Method)
- parking to wait for  <0x000000070feebf40> (a java.util.concurrent.locks.ReentrantReadWriteLock$NonfairSync)
at java.util.concurrent.locks.LockSupport.park(LockSupport.java:175)
at java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.parkAndCheckInterrupt(AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:836)
at java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.doAcquireShared(AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:967)
at java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.acquireShared(AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:1283)
at java.util.concurrent.locks.ReentrantReadWriteLock$ReadLock.lock(ReentrantReadWriteLock.java:727)
at voldemort.store.readonly.chunk.DataFileChunkSetIterator.<init>(DataFileChunkSetIterator.java:66)
at voldemort.store.readonly.chunk.ChunkedFileSet$ROKeyIterator.<init>(ChunkedFileSet.java:617)
at voldemort.store.readonly.ReadOnlyStorageEngine.keys(ReadOnlyStorageEngine.java:478)
at voldemort.server.protocol.admin.FullScanFetchStreamRequestHandler.<init>(FullScanFetchStreamRequestHandler.java:66)
```

### at voldemort.server.protocol.admin.FullScanFetchEntriesRequestHandler.(FullScanFetchEntriesRequestHandler.java:53)

```
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

But I need to see what object is at the memory location 0x000000070feebf40 . Is there an easy way to see this object ? Both YourKit and jvisualvm does not see what is in at this memory address.

I tried looking by instances but there are 300 of them for most of them which makes it really difficult to analyze.

I have used C# and there you can easily search the memory using WinDbg and sos plugin.

Comment: Project Voldemort is open source. Why don't you just examine the source to see what the object is?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you have the Heap Dump and the location of the object you're trying to find, load that dump in VisualVM and use the following Query in OQL Console

```
select heap.findObject("0x00000000fe9d4910")
```

Comment: Are you able to find your object with this :-) ?

Answer (score 0):

I do not think that 0x000000070feebf40 is an address in memory. This is object identity hash code. Identity hash-code is persistent, but address in memory is volatile (GC moves objects).

Comment: GC Moving objects is a good point. But the address is real address and not the hash code.  To be sure, in the future, I will take a thread dump before and after the memory dump to ensure that the object is not moved.

Answer (score -1):

And what exactly would you get after figuring out the object in memory? That's an internal object of `ReentrantReadWriteLock` at which the thread had parked waiting for `acquire` to succeed (which means the lock is busy). To diagnose just about any real issue, it is way better to look into the source. This part of the stack:

```
...
at java.util.concurrent.locks.ReentrantReadWriteLock$ReadLock.lock(ReentrantReadWriteLock.java:727)
at voldemort.store.readonly.chunk.DataFileChunkSetIterator.<init>(DataFileChunkSetIterator.java:66)
...
```

...means you are looking for a `ReentrantReadWriteLock.readLock().lock()` in `DataFileChunkSetIterator` constructor.

Comment: Thanks for the comment. I have more than 400 instances of ReentrantReadWriteLock , I need to find for which instance the threads are competing for. Once I got that, I can look at the object that is holding on the reference to this object and further up the chain and figure out what is going on.